# Zend Checkbox Decorator Issue

Tags: zend-framework, checkbox, zend-form

Hello I am trying to do a checkbox display like:

```
<input name="choice2" id="choice2" value="1" type="checkbox">
<label for="choice2" class="optional">Credit Card</label><br />
Some text

<input name="choice2" id="choice2" value="1" type="checkbox">
<label for="choice2" class="optional">Credit Card</label><br />
Some text
```

I got very close with the following code:

```
$lbl_spagym = 'Credit Card<br />
              <p class="description">Some text</p><br />';

$chk_spagym = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('chk_spagym');
$chk_spagym->setLabel($lbl_spagym)
           ->setDecorators(array(
           'ViewHelper',
        'Description',
            'Errors',
        array('Label', array('placement' => 'APPEND', 'escape' => false)),
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div'))
    ));
```

It renders as:

```
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="chk_bank" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_bank" id="chk_bank" value="1" checked="checked" />
<label for="chk_bank" class="optional">Credit Card<br />
                     <p class="relocation_descr">Some text</p><br />
</label></div>
```

But I need the `<p></p>` to be out of the label tag because 'some text' is a description and not a label. I played with decorators for days but can not get this behavior right. Would thanks any comments on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted my problem with:

```
$checkbox_e->setLabel($e_label)
           ->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper',
                                 'Description',
                                 'Errors',
                                 array('Label',
                                       array('placement'=>'APPEND')),
                                       array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div'))));
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a _forum_ it's a Q.A. site. If you have additional information to add to the original problem, edit your original post.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create that markup using something like

```
$form->addElement('checkbox', 'choice2', array(
    'label'      => 'Credit Card',
    'decorators' => array(
        'ViewHelper',
        array('Label', array('placement' => 'append',
                             'class'     => 'optional'))
    )
));
```

This will generate a hidden element for the checkbox "off" value but trust me, you want to keep that.

Comment: thans but that is not really what i need. I have just rephrased my question.